# How to fix Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. gradlew error

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle

**Hello I'm new to react native , and I'm using expo .
I did a production build using this command :**

```
eas build -p android
```

**and in the gradlew phase it fails and gives me this error :
**

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr]

1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

[stderr]

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr]

---

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

==============================================================================

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 6m 46s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

**I tried to remove 'expo updates' dep , and upgrade metro but it still fails anyway**